# Pick next number in sequence Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, vba

I had to create a new transaction table (tblTransactions) so I could find account balances based on the Debit(i.e. invoices) and credits(i.e. payments) fields. The table contains a field where I entered all the existing invoice numbers.

To start logging the new transactions, I created a form (frmTransactions). When I create a new invoice, I want the forms [Invoice #] field to look at Transaction table [Invoice] field column and find the highest value and + 1.  Basically, auto generating the next number in the sequence.

Comment: This field called [Invoice #]... is it on frmTransactions or is it on another form just for logging new invoices? And does [Invoice #] refer to a field in a table different to tblTransactions?

Comment: [Invoice #] is on tblTransactions, and subsequently on the frmTransactions.  It is set so it can't be duplicated, but its not in relationship to any other table or form.

Comment: What method are you using to create a new record? Is it like a "Add New Invoice" button on your frmTransactions form? Is the [Invoice #] field in your tblTransactions table definitely a number? (Sorry for all the questions, just trying to replicate your setup here.. perhaps post some screenshots of the tables and forms involved?)

Comment: I was able to come up with a solution.  What I ended up doing was adding an 'Add Invoice' button that creates a new record.  Then within that specific button, I edited the macro to include a 'SetValue' action with the expression; DMax("Invoice_Number", "tblTransactions") + 1.  When the button gets clicked, it creates a new record, and is generating the next sequenced invoice number. Thanks for your help.  All the information helps steer me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use in the BeforeInsert event:

```
Me!Invoice.Value = DMax("Invoice", "tblTransactions") + 1
```

Comment: I have tried the before insert sub and it isn't working. No value is getting entered in. I modified the Invoice field so it didn't include a '#'. Here is the code I am using. `Sub AutoInvoiceNumber_BeforeInsert()
Me.Invoice_No.Value = DMax("[Invoice_No]", "tbltransactions") + 1
End Sub`

Comment: I also tried to set the default value for that field on the form to `=DMax("[Invoice_No]","tbltransactions")+1`, which returns 1000.  It should return 2489.

Comment: I have been working on this trying to figure it out.  The [invoice_no] field on tblTransaction was set as a text data type.  I switched it over to number and it looks to be working.  Does the data type matter for DMax?

Comment: Certainly. Always use numbers for numbers in sequence. If text, DMax sorts digit by digit, thus, say, 2345 will be sorted before 67.